# switching out a heat/cool only thermostat to one with "auto" feature

Tags: thermostat

I have a Honeywell deluxe programmable thermostat with a sub-base...

- Sub-base: 32207415-011/0008
- Model: T8602D2000

The terminals that are used currently are: R W Y G (RC and O are not used)

My question is, are the wires that I have available sufficient to change to a thermostat that has the "auto" feature?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "*the "auto" feature*". Do you mean the fan switch that can be set to ON or AUTO (which I believe your unit has)? Or do you mean that you want the system to switch between heating and cooling modes automatically?

Comment: If you want to switch between heating and cooling modes automatically: that's usually very inefficient in the midrange temperatures, which is why it isn't generally done A microprocessor-based smart thermostat might be able to do this with some degree of intelligence; a basic one really is better off with a manual mode switch.

Comment: Auto changeover isn't an issue if the temps are set up right. There should be a sufficient gap between the heat and cool temp settings, but otherwise it's not an issue. Nearly any programmable thermostat has auto changeover built in, as @chris points out below.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the wires you describe are sufficient for an auto-changeover thermostat.  In fact, The Honeywell T8602D series already includes both an AUTO fan setting and an AUTO changeover setting.  See page 7 of the manual posted on the Honeywell website:

https://customer.honeywell.com/resources/techlit/TechLitDocuments/68-0000s/68-0164.pdf